# ListView custom items graphically incorrect

Tags: android, android-studio

I have defined a custom item in XML for my ListView and I want every one of them to have five fields: three already `visible` and the other two (telephone and Delete, see below) `gone` until a click action is performed. The execution works, but graphically it's not what I was expecting.

The item is defined as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt.name"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt.surname"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt.name"
        android:text="Surname"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt.id"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt.tel"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt.id"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Tel"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn.delete"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt.id"
        android:layout_marginBottom="368dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt.id"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and it gets properly inflated into the ListView, but when I click on the items, the `txt.tel TextView` and the `btn.delete Button` should appear on screen. The code I wrote is

```
ListView list= findViewById(R.id.advanced_list);
    final StudentAdapter adapter= new StudentAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.custom_list_item,
            m.getStudents()
            //this works fine, previous code omitted
    );

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView tel= view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);
            Button delete= view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

            int visible= tel.getVisibility();

            //doesn't work
            switch (visible){
                case (View.VISIBLE):
                    tel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case (View.GONE):
                    tel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Graphically, what happens is this.

[image]

---

Moreover, the item doesn't respond to other clicks anymore so I can't get them back "shrinked" with a second tap. Hope I've been clear and someone can fix both my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The execution works, but graphically it's not what I was expecting.

You set an attribute `android:layout_marginBottom="368dp"` for the `Button`, that's why the list item gets so huge.

> Moreover, the item doesn't respond to other clicks anymore so I can't get them back "shrinked" with a second tap

This happens because the expanded item contains a (visible) `Button`: if you leave out the `Button`, then the item is "shrinkable". See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160639/list-item-with-button-not-clickable-anymore) on possible workarounds

Please note also that you're likely to encounter problems when scrolling because you change the `ListView` items "from outside" (just test it with a large set of students). `ListView` items should only be changed in `getView()` and based on the current data for each position. So you should keep track of the expanded state of the rows in the Adapter, e.g. using a `List<Boolean>` or better (for performance) a `SparseBooleanArray`, and `onClick()` change the corresponding data and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: First, i really don't know the origin of that marginBottom... Sure must have been a design mistake. Second, thanks for the useful resource and for resolving my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Change the root layout's height attribute from "match_parent" to "wrap_content"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> ... </RelativeLayout>
```